# How can I parse a JSON Object/Array in Logic App

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm running into this issue where I am unable to parse an array within a JSON object that I receive from a HTTP request where I am simply looking to parse the variables within "notes" array.

Sample payload:

```
{
    "body": {
        "notes": [
            {
                "id": 777,
                "title": "Prep AM Consult - Consult Scheduled For 8/25/21",
                "body": ":: Participant:",
                "type": "Consult",
                "contact_id": 641,
                "user_id": 10457,
                "last_updated_by": {
                    "user_id": 10457,
                    "given_name": "Test",
                    "family_name": "One"
            },
            "date_created": "2021-08-25T18:00:39Z",
            "last_updated": "2021-08-25T18:00:39Z"
        },
        {
                "id": 779,
                "title": "AM Consult - Date of Original Consult 8/25/21",
                "body": ":: Participants",
                "type": "Consult",
                "contact_id": 641,
                "user_id": 10457,
                "last_updated_by": {
                    "user_id": 10457,
                    "given_name": "Test",
                    "family_name": "Two"
            },
            "date_created": "2021-08-25T18:29:14Z",
            "last_updated": "2021-08-25T18:29:14Z"
        }
    ],
    "count": 9,
    "next": "https://api.infusionsoft.com/",
    "previous": "https://api.infusionsoft.com/"
}
}
```

Here is the schema that Azure generates from the payload above:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "count": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "next": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "notes": {
            "items": {
                "properties": {
                    "body": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "contact_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "date_created": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "last_updated": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "last_updated_by": {
                        "properties": {
                            "family_name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "given_name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "user_id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "user_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "id",
                    "title",
                    "body",
                    "type",
                    "contact_id",
                    "user_id",
                    "last_updated_by",
                    "date_created",
                    "last_updated"
                ],
                "type": "object"
            },
            "type": "array"
        },
        "previous": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Is the best method to try to create a CSV table to load the data into, and if so do I need to create a variable for just the "notes" first?

Comment: I found another path forward being able to set individual variables in the For Each loop. Feel free to leave any opinions as I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: provided an answer without foreach !!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I parse a JSON Object/Array in Logic App

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Parse_Json Schema:`**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "body": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "notes": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "title": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "body": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "contact_id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "user_id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "last_updated_by": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "user_id": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "given_name": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "family_name": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "date_created": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "last_updated": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "required": [
                            "id",
                            "title",
                            "body",
                            "type",
                            "contact_id",
                            "user_id",
                            "last_updated_by",
                            "date_created",
                            "last_updated"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "count": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "next": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "previous": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Code View:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['notes']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Create_CSV_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "format": "CSV",
                    "from": "@outputs('Compose')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": {
                                "body": {
                                    "count": 9,
                                    "next": "https://api.infusionsoft.com/",
                                    "notes": [
                                        {
                                            "body": ":: Participant:",
                                            "contact_id": 641,
                                            "date_created": "2021-08-25T18:00:39Z",
                                            "id": 777,
                                            "last_updated": "2021-08-25T18:00:39Z",
                                            "last_updated_by": {
                                                "family_name": "One",
                                                "given_name": "Test",
                                                "user_id": 10457
                                            },
                                            "title": "Prep AM Consult - Consult Scheduled For 8/25/21",
                                            "type": "Consult",
                                            "user_id": 10457
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "body": ":: Participants",
                                            "contact_id": 641,
                                            "date_created": "2021-08-25T18:29:14Z",
                                            "id": 779,
                                            "last_updated": "2021-08-25T18:29:14Z",
                                            "last_updated_by": {
                                                "family_name": "Two",
                                                "given_name": "Test",
                                                "user_id": 10457
                                            },
                                            "title": "AM Consult - Date of Original Consult 8/25/21",
                                            "type": "Consult",
                                            "user_id": 10457
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "previous": "https://api.infusionsoft.com/"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@variables('var')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "body": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "count": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "next": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "notes": {
                                        "items": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "body": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "contact_id": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                },
                                                "date_created": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "id": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                },
                                                "last_updated": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "last_updated_by": {
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "family_name": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "given_name": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "user_id": {
                                                            "type": "integer"
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "type": "object"
                                                },
                                                "title": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "type": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "user_id": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "id",
                                                "title",
                                                "body",
                                                "type",
                                                "contact_id",
                                                "user_id",
                                                "last_updated_by",
                                                "date_created",
                                                "last_updated"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    },
                                    "previous": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```